# How to get records according to column data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in sql whose name is `Trans` which contain 4 columns

```
CustomerID  int
TransDate   datetime
TransType   char(1)
Amount      float
```

`CustomerID` can contain duplicate ID's but record contain different `TransDate` or `TransType` or `Amount`. `TransType` contain `'c'` for credit and `'d'` for debit.

I want to select `CustomerId`, `year`, `CreditAmount` and `DebitAmount` where `CreditAmount` is amount where `TransType` is `'c'` and `DebitAmount` is amount where `TransType` is `'d'`. `Year` is calculated from `TransDate` which contain date and time.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Provide table structure (keys/indexes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select customerid,
       datepart(yyyy, transdate) as yr,
       sum(case when transtype = 'c' then amount else 0 end) as creditamount,
       sum(case when transtype = 'd' then amount else 0 end) as debitamount
  from trans
 group by customerid,
          datepart(yyyy, transdate)
```

This does assume you want the **total** credits, for each year, and total debits, for each year, for each customer.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select CustomerId, year, CreditAmount and DebitAmount where
>   CreditAmount is amount where TransType is 'c' and DreditAmount is
>   amount where TransType is 'd'. Year is calculated from TransDate which
>   contain date and time.

I am not sure that I understand you correctly, but you can check:

```
SELECT 
   CustomerId
  ,[Year]         = YEAR(TransDate)
  ,[CreditAmount] = Amount 
  ,[DebitAmount]  = (SELECT Amount 
                     FROM Trans t1 
                     WHERE t1.CustomerId = t.CustomerId 
                       AND t1.TransDate = t.TransDate 
                       AND t1.TransType = 'd')
FROM Trans t
WHERE t.TransType = 'c';
```

I assumed that `CustomerId/TranDate/TransType` are unique.